# What is the fastest way to get to documentation for Ruby?

Tags: ruby, documentation

Say I'm writing some ruby code and I want to use the standard Date type to get the current date. Instead of using a search engine, is there a faster way to find the documentation for this class?  I know I can get the methods for Date by typing `Date.methods`, but as far as I know this doesn't provide details about argument types or return value.

Editor-specific answers are welcomed.  My editor of choice is Emacs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bookmark the [ruby core docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/)

Use your web browser's find-text command.

Unexpected as it may seem, I find this is actually quicker than using `ri`, which for some reason seems to take ages to start up.

It is also much better than `ri` because the HTML page lists all the documentation for all the methods on a single page. Often methods are related to others, and switching between 2 `ri`'s is painful

Answer (score 3):

On your console use "ri"

```
ri Date
```

That works with all classes. (e.g. ri String)
To see documentation for a particular method you use this:

```
ri Date#yourMethod
```

Comment: or rather ri 'Date.yourMethod' ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The canonical source for Ruby documentation is [Ruby-doc](http://ruby-doc.org/) - the two links there which are of the most interest are [core](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/) and [standard library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/).  You get a javadoc-style representation which usually covers argument types and return values.  You can even make your own with [RDoc](http://rdoc.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: The canonical source for Ruby documentation is the source code.  Generating the documentation will give you (documentation) 100% oriented for your version of Ruby.  You can access that with `ri`, and `ri`, provided you generate documentation for your gems, will also show your specific documentation for those versions of the gems as well.

Answer (score 0):

For those of you who want docs from within vanilla IRB

1. Follow [these](https://github.com/dadooda/ori/blob/master/README_RI_CORE.md) instructions  for setting up the core RI documentation. As of writing, the steps are

   ```
   $ cd ~/.rvm/src
   $ rvm docs generate-ri
   ```
2. Now you can view docs for a specific method on the command line using the `ri` command. To invoke it from within IRB, use the help command:

   ```
   $ irb
   irb(main):001:0> help 'String#chomp'
   ```